# How to have two patterns in re

Tags: python, regex

Say a have a list of words, and would like to go through each word to see if it matches a pattern "a?e", where ? can be any alphanumeric character.  Also, I would like to ignore words that contain '-' (a dash).  How do I do this using regex?

Here's what I currently have:

```
for word in words:
    found = re.findall(r'([a]\w{1}[e])(^((?!(-)).)*$)', word)
    if found:
        print(word)
```

For example:  ['snake', 'take', 'want', 'sane','1', 'snakke', 's-ake']

I would like to filter out: `snake, take, sane`

edited: sorry there was a mismatch with my question/code

Comment: can you provide some sample input and desired output?

Comment: What is the reasoning to try and do this in one expression? Wouldn't it be simpler to filter out all the words that don't have '-' then perform the second regex if they pass the first?

Comment: If you use ```\w``` or ```[a-zA-Z0-9]``` for the ```?``` in your pattern it will NOT match a word with a dash in it.

Comment: The *pattern* in your question is different than the pattern in your code example.

Comment: wwii, sorry I updated the code.  jacoblaw, please see example above.  @dustyjuicebox, Yes i was thinking of doing that also, but wouldnt that take longer? I was thinking having it done with regex will be faster.  I could be wrong, but I guess I am also curious how to do it with regex alone

Comment: Try [`r'(?i)\b(?<!-)\w*a[a-z]e\w*\b(?!-)'`](https://regex101.com/r/XHdYe4/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This solution works.  Thanks.

Comment: @user1179317: I added as an answer with explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
r'(?i)\b(?<!-)\w*a[a-z]e\w*\b(?!-)'
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XHdYe4/1).

**Details**

- `(?i)` - same as `re.I`, ignores case
- `\b`  - word boundary
- `(?<!-)` - no hyphen before the word boundary is allowed
- `\w*` - zero or more word chars  (if you want to only match letters, replace with `[^\W\d_]*`)
- `a` - an `a` letter
- `[a-z]` - any ASCII letter
- `e` - an `e` letter
- `\w*` - 0+ word chars (or use `[^\W\d_]*` as hinted above)
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!-)` - not followed with a `-`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `match` instead of `findall`.  `match` will match the whole string, while `findall` will look for substrings that match your regex.

```
found = (w for w in words if re.match(r'g\wo', word))
```